# Pc Upgrade, bringing windows 10 with me

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade, desktop-computer

Around 5 years ago I got a prebuilt acer PC which came with windows 7 home. When the windows 10 update came out, I upgraded to it within a few months, once it had been reviewed quite thoroughly. Now I am building a new PC with all new parts and am confused as to whether or not I can move my windows 10 licence to this new PC or if I have to buy a new copy. The internet seems to contradict itself quite a bit and I can find just a "Yes" or "No" answer.

Comment: There should be no confusion.  You have an OEM license that is tied to the Acer PC.  It is not transferable.

Comment: "round 5 years ago I got a prebuilt acer PC which came with windows 7 home. " - This means neither the Windows 7 license nor the Windows 10 license can be transfered to another PC.  You need to purchase Windows 10 if you want to run Windows 10 on the new hardware.  Proper research before asking a question is highly encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Since your copy of Windows came with on a prebuilt PC, it is only licensed for for one single device. You will not be able to move it to a new PC. There is no gray area on this one. I can say unequivocally that the answer to your question is No. 
It is written clearly in the [Microsoft License Terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20oem%20license%20terms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)